# How can you loop through a variable declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

So I found myself repeating some of my javascript and was wondering if there is a way that I can assign variables in a loop but with an incremented number at the end.

So this is my repeating code that I want looped:

```
var $d1 = $(".dot-1");
var $d2 = $(".dot-2");
var $d3 = $(".dot-3");
var $d4 = $(".dot-4");
var $d5 = $(".dot-5");
var $d6 = $(".dot-6");
var $d7 = $(".dot-7");
var $d8 = $(".dot-8");
var $d9 = $(".dot-9");
var $d10 = $(".dot-10");
var $d11 = $(".dot-11");
var $d12 = $(".dot-12");
var $d13 = $(".dot-13");
var $d14 = $(".dot-14");
var $d15 = $(".dot-15");
var $d16 = $(".dot-16");
var $d17 = $(".dot-17");
var $d18 = $(".dot-18");
var $d19 = $(".dot-19");
var $d20 = $(".dot-20");
var $d21 = $(".dot-21");
var $d22 = $(".dot-22");
var $d23 = $(".dot-23");
var $d24 = $(".dot-24");
var $d25 = $(".dot-25");
var $d26 = $(".dot-26");
var $d27 = $(".dot-27");
var $d28 = $(".dot-28");
var $d29 = $(".dot-29");
var $d30 = $(".dot-30");
```

As you can see its the same thing but with an incremented number in the variable name and class selector. Is there a way to loop through this?

I also found myself stuck trying to loop through this as well:

```
$(".stop").click(function() {
    player1.pauseVideo();
    player2.pauseVideo();
    player3.pauseVideo();
    player4.pauseVideo();
});
```

Again I see a repeating process with the same code just incremented numbers at the end. So I see a potential loop in this case as well.

**UPDATE**

For those who are curious on what those .dots are used for it would be something like this.

```
$d1.click(function(){
    $(".content-1").removeClass("zoomOut").addClass('zoomIn');
});
$d2.click(function(){
    $(".content-2").removeClass("zoomOut").addClass('zoomIn');
});
$d3.click(function(){
    $(".content-3").removeClass("zoomOut").addClass('zoomIn');
});
```

Comment: I don't see a reason for doing this. `$(".dot").eq(29)` should be fine (assuming you drop the -n from the classnames)

Comment: Keeps my code more DRY

Comment: I mean, creating numbered veriables.

Comment: Why don't you store these in arrays?

Comment: why do you need so many unique classes in the first place? Would be better to look at using common classes first. Likely doing a lot that isn't needed. Show some html

Comment: Well each class needs to be unique because each of them has a click event that triggers something different for each of them.

Comment: @LucasSantos Something is wrong in your logic then

Comment: Show us what those click handlers do. Creating 30 different handlers makes no sense either

Comment: I have updated my code so you can see how I am using the click events that I am talking about.

Comment: After looking at your update I would repeat that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @lucas I can see a pattern in your click handlers. Improvise.

Comment: @SalmanA I am not sure how I would do that because they have separate functions and selectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're okay with your variables being in an array (which probably would be a lot more usable), you can do this:

```
var $d = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
  $d.push($(".dot-"+i));
}
```

You can then access elements with `$d[index]`, where index is a number 0-29 (corresponding to ".dot-1" through ".dot-30").

Comment: This would result in the first 'dot' being dot-0, since the first index is 0. So you'd have `dot-0` through `dot-29` not 1 through 30

Comment: Maybe you should add that each '`dot`' could be accessed via `$d[index]` where `$[0]` would be `$('.dot-1');` etc...

Comment: Another solid comment. Thanks @diemaus, added that.

Comment: Your answer as well as @shadowizard and Joy works and is great! I am going to choose yours as the answer because it's simple and works. I like storing it in an array. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use syntax `[]` to define a dynamic property on some object:

```
var myVariables = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    myVariables['$d' + i] = $(".dot-" + i);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer; even though OP's code could be improved upon a lot.

Comment: What's your reason for using window?

Comment: @LucasSantos updated answer. Yes, just lazy to type. I created an object `myVariables` outside now.

Comment: the `global` object in javascript is called `window` `window['x']` would be the same variable as `x` (if defined with `x = 10;`, and without the `var`-keyword). However, dumping so many global variables would be considered bad practice in almost all cases.

Comment: much like @oxguy3 answer but within an object. I like it and works as well

Answer (score 5):

You better have a different, better logic to begin with.

Give all the elements the same class `dot` then to access specific element, use the `.eq()` method:

```
$(".dot").eq(11)
```

Would give you back the 12<sup>th</sup> element, for example. I really can't see any reason to give separate class to each element.

Based on comments, looks like your goal is identify which element was clicked, to do that you can use the `.index()` method like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".dot").click(function() {
        alert("my index is: " + $(this).index() + ", hooray!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dot">1</div>
<div class="dot">2</div>
<div class="dot">3</div>
```

Comment: This would still be repeating code though. You would have to use .eq() 30 times to access all of the .dot..    ps. I do have a class of .dot on all of them.

Comment: Why you try to use it 30 times? What's the bigger picture? Explain this, and we'll show you how to do that without repeating 30 times.

Comment: @LucasSantos no, you don't need all those variables... you only need one collection and your other logic would do whatever is needed to define specific ones to interact with. There is something wrong at a higher level with whatever you do with all these variables

Comment: each `.dot` has a click event to them that triggers something unique

Comment: @LucasSantos so in that "something unique" you can check what element triggered it by accessing the argument

Comment: @lucas `var $dots = $(".dot").click(function() { alert( $dots.index(this) })` ... one handler for all your logic. Again there is something wrong at higher level of your approach and it is not scaleable

Comment: @LucasSantos You should provide concrete example in question itself of why would you need to declare so many variables because anyway you don't have to...

Comment: Each of my `.dot` class has a many different STYLES and FUNCTIONS which is why I needed them to be unique in that nature.

Comment: @LucasSantos So don't ask to DRY it if you don't want to DRY it

Comment: @LucasSantos and likely some array simplifications of all those styles would help also. This DRY of some variables is not going to make your app any simpler

Comment: @shadow `$(this).index()` does not work the way you expect, for example, when `.dot` classes have different parents. But the idea is right.

Comment: This worked really nice and is another great option.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=1; i<31; i++){
    window['$d' + i] = $(".dot-" + i);
}
```

And

```
$(".stop").click(function() {
    for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
        window['player' + i].pauseVideo();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you intentions are with the loop, but something like this might work?

```
 $(function(){
    var x = $("*[class^='$d']").size();
    var z =null;
    while (i < x) {
      doSomthing();  
    }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `eval();`

```
$(".stop").click(function()
{
    for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++)
    { 
        eval('player'+ i +'.pauseVideo();');
    }
});
```